# How to make elements the same margins and width?

Tags: html, css, select, width, margin

```
<div id="divL">
<input name="email" type="text" placeholder="input text">
<div class="divInput">divInput</div>
<div class="divtxt">divtxt</div>
<input name="sname" type="text" placeholder="input text">
<select name="srodstvo">
    <option value="1">select</option>
    <option value="2">323</option>
</select>
<div class="divtxt">divtxt</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#divL{
    width:45%;
    margin:5vh 0 0 5vw;
    border:thin solid blue;
}
input[type="text"], .divtxt, .divInput, select{
    width:100%;
    margin:4px 0;
    padding:4px;
    border:thin solid #999;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

All elements have the same margins, padding and width. But the distance between second end the third element is different and `select` is shorter !?

fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C6FEV/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the width, add this `CSS` rule:

```
input, select
{
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

To fix the margins: add `display: inline-block` to...

```
input[type="text"], .divtxt, .divInput, select
{
    width:100%;
    margin:4px 0;
    padding:4px;
    border:thin solid #999;
    border-radius:3px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's it working: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/Y5aVB/4/embedded/result/

Comment: Leniel, solved, thanks. But Could you explain ? Why I need `display:inline-block` to set the margins?

Comment: That's because you have different types of elements: `<div>`s and `<input>`s and `margin` affects them differently. Doing `display:inline-block` you force them to behave equally. For more info about the `display` property, see here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 1):

It is due to `Box-Sizing`. 
`Input` has box-sizing is `content-box` whereas `select` is by default has `border-box` as `box-sizing`. So you can change the box-sizing property for the select by adding this to your markup

```
select
{
   box-sizing:content-box;
}
```

Without setting this property `select` has less height than the other elements (In Chrome).

One more thing is after setting this your elements are still outside the parent container. It is because you have put their `width=100%` along with `padding : 4px` which make them bigger than `100%` of parent. So just set 0 padding from left and right.

```
Padding:4px 0;
```

And for the uneven margin in third element add

```
display:inline-block;
```

[Update Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6FEV/13/)

Comment: Sachin, did you try? No result.

Comment: @SunSky have a look into jsFiddle example

Comment: Looked at your fiddle.  Nothing changed, visually.

Comment: @DavidStarkey Look at the width of the select. it is same as other elements whereas it was not in the posted one

Comment: Not, all the widths are exactly the same as OP.  At least in Firefox 23.0.1 they are.

Comment: Sachin, I see, but it's ok for me. Could you help about the distance between the second and the third element ? It's different.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a second value to `padding`

```
padding:4px 0;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6FEV/4/)

Tested in Firefox 23

[image: Screenshot]

**UPDATE**:

To fix the margin between elements 2 and 3, set all 4 sides in `padding`

```
margin:4px 0 0 0;
```

To keep the spacing at the bottom, set a `padding` in the outer `div`

```
padding:0 0 4px 0;
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6FEV/11/)

Comment: The distance between the second and the third element is smaller !

Comment: So it is.  I'm horrible at noticing stuff like that :P

Comment: David, but i need the bottom margin as well. Using `margin:4px 0 4px 0` - doesn't work. It seems that solution is `display:inline-block`, although I don't understand why. Anyway, thanks a lot. Let's say solved